# Get input from user on gradle build in android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android Studio IDE and I need to have the option to assign a variable in my code with a value that will be entered on running the apk or while generating an apk.

I understand that I cannot use `System.console`, is there any other solution?

Comment: You should be able to access the `System.console` as long as you are not running gradle as a daemon.  Try adding `-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false` to your gradle command

Comment: Thank you @drew Im not building from command line. If I use `System.console` in build.gradle I get error that console is null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to do this either using a command line input or a swing dialog within Android Studio.  The sample task below will display a dialog if the gradle is running as a daemon and as a command line prompt if it's not.

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder

task ask << {
  def keyPassPhrase
  def console = System.console()
  if (console) {
      keyPassPhrase = console.readLine('> Please enter key pass phrase: ')
  } else {
      new SwingBuilder().edt {
          dialog(modal: true,
                  title: 'Enter credentials',
                  alwaysOnTop: true,
                  resizable: false,
                  locationRelativeTo: null,
                  pack: true,
                  show: true
          ) {
              vbox {
                  label(text: "Please enter key passphrase:")
                  input = passwordField()
                  button(defaultButton: true, text: 'OK', actionPerformed: {
                      keyPassPhrase = input.password;
                      dispose();
                  })
              }
          }
      }
  }
  print "Key pass phrase: ${keyPassPhrase}"
}
```

(With thanks to Tim Roes for the groovy solution  https://www.timroes.de/2014/01/19/using-password-prompts-with-gradle-build-files/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @drew !

Comment: How to handle building on a headless server with no ability to export DISPLAY? I was using `ant` but latest gradle seems to have broken that option.

Comment: Did this suddenly stop working for anyone else with `gradle-4.10.1` and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0` after updating to Android Studio 3.3?  Now when typing in the password I always get "keystore was tampered with" (i.e., bad password) prompt.  The cursor flickers which makes me think it's seeing input from another source that corrupts the password when it's being typed.

Comment: Yeah, this stopped working. So does reading from the console.

Answer (score 3):

@drew's solution is excellent, but it only accepts a single password for both keystore and key.  I needed a solution that would allow two different passwords, one for keystore and another for key.

Not being very familiar with Groovy, it took some trial-and-error to extend this to two input fields - here's what I ended up with:

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder

...

/**
 * Ask for keystore/key passwords on the command line or popup UI
 */
task askForPasswords << {
    def console = System.console()
    def storePw
    def keyPw

    if (console) {
        // Must create String because System.readPassword() returns char[]
        // (and assigning that below fails silently)
        storePw = new String(console.readPassword("\nKeystore password: "))
        keyPw = new String(console.readPassword("Key password: "))
    } else {
        // Gradle is running as a daemon - prompt user to enter passwords via popup UI
        new SwingBuilder().edt {
            dialog(modal: true, title: 'Enter credentials', alwaysOnTop: true, resizable: false,
                    locationRelativeTo: null, pack: true, show: true
            ) {
                vbox {
                    label(text: "Keystore passphrase:")
                    textField id: "storeText", input = passwordField()
                    label(text: "Key passphrase:")
                    textField id: "keyText", input = passwordField()
                    button(defaultButton: true, text: 'OK', actionPerformed: {
                        storePw = storeText.text;
                        keyPw = keyText.text;
                        dispose();
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }

    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = storePw
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = keyPw
}
```

...which looks like this:

[image]

See a working example of this at https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android/blob/master/onebusaway-android/build.gradle#L291.

Comment: This quite late, but can you tell me where I can put that code for it to actually work?

Comment: See working example at https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android/blob/master/onebusaway-android/build.gradle#L291.

Comment: I tried to put an incorrect credentials and it still continue to build. Is that okay or it  supposed to failed.

Comment: It will eventually fail at the signing stage, which is late in the build.